# How to remove five consecutive bytes?

Tags: vb.net

Want in the variable search and replace five consecutive bytes. How can I do this?

- The bytes that I want to replace: `0000000D0A` --> `0D0A`

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

If your data are stored in a string, use the Substring method to get the part of the string you like.

With your sample:

- The bytes that I want to replace: `0000000D0A` --> `0D0A`

there is a Problem: I assume, you showed us the hex representation:

- The bytes that I want to replace: `00 00 00 0D 0A` --> `0D 0A`

I interpret this as you would like to remove the first 3 bytes:

```
// C#
yournewString = youroldString.Substr(3); 

' VB.NET
yournewString = youroldString.Substr(3)
```